# $a$ is integral over $I$ iff $R[a]$ is finitely generated $R-$module and $a\in\sqrt{IR[a]}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to ask a little question about definition. Let $S/R$ be a ring extension, and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. I read a sentence in a handout in commutative algebra that says "$a$ is integral over $I$ iff $R[a]$ is finitely generated $R-$module and $a\in\sqrt{IR[a]}$". However, what does the symbol $IR[a]$ mean? I have totally no ideas.

Does this relate to 1 or 2?
[image]

Comment: The ideal generated by $I$ in $R[a]$.

Comment: @jgon Is the symbol standard? In what place this symbol first appear in introductory algebra course? I don't remember seeing it.

Comment: it's not a single symbol, it's the juxtaposition of $I$ with $R[a]$, denoting the ideal-module product (which since $R[a]$ is the ring itself is the ideal generated by $I$ in $R[a]$). The notation $IS$ for the ideal generated by $I$ (where $I$ is an ideal of a subring, $R$) in the ring $S$ is standard.

Comment: @jgon I'm still confused. Does this relate to 1 or 2 in my picture which I just added? Since a ring over a subring can be a module, will these two different symbols definition conflict?

Comment: those two definitions are compatible, and both give the correct interpretation here.

Comment: @jgon Hmm... I still have a question. You and the answer both mentioned the pharse "the ideal generated by $I$ in/of $S$" as "$IS$". However, I just checked Dummit&Foote's, Hungerford's text, I didn't find such English definition (the only thing I found is **the ideal generated by a set**, the traditional definition of $(X)$, where $X$ is a subset of a ring, which means the smallest ideal containing $X$). Where do you see this terminology?

Comment: An ideal is a subset of the ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B/A$ is a ring extension and $I$ is an ideal of $A$, then $IB$ is the ideal of $B$ generated by $I$. So:
$$IB := \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i b_i : n\geq 1, x_i\in I, b_i\in B \right\}$$

Comment: You mentioned the pharse "the ideal generated by $I$ in/of $B$" as "$IB$". However, I just checked Dummit&Foote's, Hungerford's text, I didn't find such English terminology (the only thing I found is the traditional definition of $(X)$, where $X$ is a subset of a ring, which means the smallest ideal containing $X$). Where do you see this terminology?

Comment: It's the same terminology. If $R$ is a ring and $X\subseteq R$, then the ideal generated by $X$ is $(X)$. Standard notation for this is $(X)=RX$. The notation $(X)$ does not mention which ring you're working with: for example if $X=\{2\}$, what is the ideal generated by $X$? Well, I didn't tell you *which ring* I'm generating it in. If $R=\mathbb{Z}$, then $(2)=2\mathbb{Z}$. If $R=\mathbb{Q}$, then $(2)=\mathbb{Q}$. It's just clarity of notation.

Comment: I see! Very grateful!